# How many ways are there to choose $k$ numbers from first $n$ natural numbers such that any two numbers differ by at most $d$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to choose $k$ distinct numbers from $n$ consecutive natural numbers such that any two numbers differ by at most $d$?

The solution of the similar problem is done when difference is at least $d$.  But what about when the difference is at most $d$?

Answer (score 3):

Assume WLOG that the numbers are $1, 2, ..., n$ and assume $k-1\leq d<n$.

Let's focus on numbers $1, 2, ..., d+1$. Obviously, the difference between any two numbers is at most $d$. We can choose $k$ numbers in $\binom{d+1}{k}$ ways.

Now focus on numbers $2, 3, ..., d+2$. Since we have already considered all $k-subsets$ on the first $d$ numbers, we have to include $d+2$ in our new choices, hence, leading to $\binom{d}{k-1}$ ways.

Focus on $3, 4, ..., d+3$. Same logic as above.

Repeat this $n-d$ times and get a total of

$$\underbrace{\binom{d+1}{k} + \binom{d}{k-1} + ... + \binom{d}{k-1}}_\text{n-d terms}=\binom{d+1}{k}+(n-d-1)\binom{d}{k-1}$$.